# Statements about a twice differentiable function

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

Can you help me to prove or disprove?

We  have a function $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable, such that as $x\rightarrow+\infty$

(a) $xf(x) \rightarrow+\infty$
(b) $xf''(x) \rightarrow+\infty$

then $xf'(x) \rightarrow+\infty$.

---

Also demonstrate that if only (a) or only (b) is valid then the statement is false.

Comment: Is this a command directed at the M.SE community or do you have a question to ask?

Comment: this is the problem and I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure you got the problem right. Also, it would be more appropriate to phrase it as a question, rather than a command.

For the solution, start with (b) (you don't really need (a) ). You have for sufficiently large $x$: $x f''(x) > 1$, so you can choose some huge constant $C$ so that $x f''(x) > 1 - \frac{C}{x}$ as long as $x > 1$. This gives you $f''(x) > \frac{1}{x} - \frac{C}{x^2}$. Integrate this to get $$f'(x) > f'(1) + \ln(x) + \frac{C}{2x} - \frac{C}{2} = \ln(x) + O(1)$$
where $O(1)$ stands for "something bounded". In particular, $f'(x) \to \infty$, and even more so $xf'(x) \to \infty$. It so happens that since $f'(x) > 1$ for large enough $x$, you can also derive that $f(x) \to \infty$, so (a) follows from (b).

Comment: this is good but in theory I should be able to prove it without the use of integral, only with the derivation. In the text of the problem say that you want to use the Taylor expansion of taylor with the rest of lagrange in a generic point $ x_0 $.